# Tsql function to return parent id of the direct parent, not the grandparent

Tags: t-sql

This is the structure of my database: I have a table `tblMenu` and table `tblProduct`. One menu can have multiple products. That relationship is stored in the `tblMenu_products` table. However, one product can be consisted of multiple products and multiple ingredients. That relationship is saved in the `tblProduct_Ingredients` table, in which I have a column called `table` so that I know if the ingredient is from `tblProduct` or `tblIngredient`.

What I need to do is this: for one menu, list all of its direct and indirect items. That means all of the products in the menu, and all of their products and ingredients, and all of their products anmd ingredients, and so on.

This is my function in `tsql`:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fnListInfo](@menu_id int) returns @res table(
 [id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
 [itemId] INT,
 [name] NVARCHAR(255),
 [type] NVARCHAR(20),
 [parent] int
)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @res

    SELECT product.product_id, product.name, product.type, menuProducts.parent
    FROM tblMenu menu
    JOIN dbo.tblMenu_products menuProducts on menu.menu_id = menuProducts.menu_products_menu
    JOIN dbo.tblProduct product ON menuProducts.menu_products_product = product.product_id
    WHERE menu.menu_id = @menu_id

    insert into @res
        SELECT t.*
        FROM @res r
        CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTest(r.itemId, r.id) AS t
        WHERE r.type = 'product'

 RETURN
END
GO
```

In `fnTest` I send an input parameter of the product id and get all of the items for that product (sons, grandsons, etc.).

That function shows me the correct items I need to get.

Now what I need to do is this: `fnListInfo` has an id column which is autoincremented. I also have `parentId` which needs to show me the autoincremented id of the item's direct parent.

The problem happens when setting the `parentid` in `fnTest`. here's `fnTest`:

```
create function dbo.fnTest(@product_id INT, @autoincrement_id INT) returns @res table(
    [itemId] INT,
    [name] NVARCHAR(255),
    [type] NVARCHAR(20),
    [parent] INT)   
begin   
    ;WITH ret AS(
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.tblProduct_Ingredients
        WHERE product_ingredient_product = @product_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT prodIng.*
        FROM dbo.tblProduct_Ingredients AS prodIng
        INNER JOIN ret AS r ON r.product_ingredient_ingredient = prodIng.product_ingredient_product AND r.product_ingredient_table = 'tblProduct'
    )
    insert into @res
        select  ing.ing_id, ing.name, 'ingredient', @autoincrement_id /*parent*/
        FROM ret
        join dbo.tblIng as ing ON ret.product_ingredient_ingredient = ing.ing_id
        WHERE ret.product_ingredient_table = 'tblIng'

        UNION

        SELECT  product.product_id, product.name, 'product', @autoincrement_id /*parent*/
        FROM ret
        join dbo.tblProduct as product ON ret.product_ingredient_ingredient = product.product_id
        WHERE ret.product_ingredient_table = 'tblProduct'
    return
end
GO
```

The problem is that I set the parent to the items to the product in the menu, not to their direct product parent.

So, let's say we have a menu 'Breakfast' and in it I have a product 'Omelette Extra' which has a product of 'Omelette' and ingredient tomatoes. And let's say 'Omelette' has ingredient Egg. With my method above, I get that the `parentId` of Egg is 'Omelette extra', but I need to get 'Omelette'. How do i do this?